# Posting JSON on my "public/visible" domain (via MySQL), safety concern

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is like a security question to see if my JSON would be vulnerable for hackers/injection.
I have the JSON posted on my domain that I rent from a domainhotelcompany (www.one.com) and it is not password protected or something like that as you can see in the code.
 Via a httprequest from my App I then gather the JSON from that ”public/visible” webpage.

Could this be vulnerable and risky? And if so, what would be my best bet?
 This is the code that I am currently working with:

```
<?php

class ConnectionInfo 
{   
    public $conn; 
    public function GetConnection() {

        $this->conn = mysqli_connect("serv", "user","pass", "db") or die(mysqli_error($mysql_pekare));

    }
}

$connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
$connectionInfo->GetConnection();

if (!$connectionInfo->conn)
{
    echo 'No Connection';
}else{
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM  Team ORDER BY objectId';

    $stmt = mysqli_query($connectionInfo->conn, $query);

    if (!$stmt)
    {
        //Query failed
        echo 'Query failed';
    }else{
        $contacts = array(); 

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {
            $contact = array("Image" => utf8_encode ($row['image']),
                             "Name" => utf8_encode ($row['name']),
                            "Role" => utf8_encode ($row['role']),
                            "objectid" => utf8_encode ($row['objectId']));

            array_push($contacts, $contact);
        }

        echo json_encode(array('results' => $contacts), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by vulnerable or risky. Other that the fact that anybody can get this script to return its data what risks are you thinking about

Comment: I see. So it is not possible to SQL-inject my current code then? And it is not possible for hackers to somehow get the mysql user, pass, db, serv info?

Comment: Your script does not accept any input. The query does not use any variables in its makeup so no its not vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: _And it is not possible for hackers to somehow get the mysql user, pass, db, serv info_ Not from running this script. But hackers dont alway come at you head on. If thet get into your server some other way anything is possible

Comment: I see i see. Awesome. That answers my question perfectly. I should be all set then to release my first "professional" app. I will for sure accept this as an answer.

Comment: No need to bother